# MySQL Union ALL result

Tags: mysql, sql

Now working.. You must lookup all results the query teh sub query.

```
SELECT Extn, COUNT(*) as Total_Calls, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(cldp_talk_time/1000)) as Talk_Time, SUM(cost/100000) as 'Total_Cost' from( 

select clngp_digits as Extn, cldp_talk_time, cost from cr20140130 where record_type = 'D' or record_type = 'C'
union all
select cldp_digits as Extn, cldp_talk_time, cost from cr20140130 where record_type = 'D' or record_type = 'B'
union all
select clngp_digits as Extn, cldp_talk_time, cost from cr20140131 where record_type = 'D' or record_type = 'C'
union all
select cldp_digits as Extn, cldp_talk_time, cost from cr20140131 where record_type = 'D' or record_type = 'B'

) t group by Extn order by Extn ASC
```

Comment: Your query is not doing what you think it is, and it is probably not the right approach to get the results you want.  Can you edit your question and add sample data and desired results?

Comment: You are right I have changed it now.

Comment: SELECT Extn, COUNT(*) as Total_Calls, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(cldp_talk_time/1000)) as Talk_Time, SUM(cost/100000) as 'Total_Cost' from( 

select clngp_digits as Extn, cldp_talk_time, cost from cr20140130 where record_type = 'D' or record_type = 'C'
union all
select cldp_digits as Extn, cldp_talk_time, cost from cr20140130 where record_type = 'D' or record_type = 'B'
union all
select clngp_digits as Extn, cldp_talk_time, cost from cr20140131 where record_type = 'D' or record_type = 'C'

) t group by Extn order by Extn ASC

Comment: . . You can go back to the question and click on the `edit` option immediately at the end.  You can then add the query into the question and make whatever changes you like.

Comment: Also, if you're still struggling, consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET. (I have a felling that you are making this more difficult than it needs to be!)